# UITableView header title with undefined number of sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, switch-statement

If I have a UITableView that it has `[arrayofStudents count]` sections:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [arrayofStudents count]
}
```

And then I want to make a title header for every section(notice that the number of sections is related to the size of arrayofStudent)

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

       switch (section) {
       case //if it is the first section :
            return [arrayofStudents objectAtIndex:0];
            break;
        case //if it is the second section:
            return [arrayofStudents objectAtIndex:1];
            break;
        //case until arrive to the count of arrayofStudents
        default:
            break;
}
```

The number of the case statements is related to the count of arrayofStudents, if I have 10 elements in arrayofStudents then I'll have 10 sections.
How to build that in the switch case statement?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
[arrayofStudents objectAtIndex:section];
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

The case statement looks redundant: since both sections and `NSArray`s are indexed starting with zero, the same can be achieved with

```
return [arrayofStudents objectAtIndex:section];
```

perhaps with some additional argument checking at the beginning to handle the default.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
            return [arrayofStudents objectAtIndex:section];

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: So simple that I did not think about it :/

Comment: To be fair I marked the FIRST (correct) answer even that your answer is more clear. Sorry man.

Comment: No prob. but if you see the answer time then I answered before Divz.